# Upgrading android on device with small memory

Tags: updates, samsung, 5.1-lollipop

Hi I have an android Core Prime with 8GB internal storage and a 16GB sd card
Currently it has andriod 4.4.4 installed 
It has downloaded an upgrade to 5.1.1

It says it requires 3gb of space for the install of which I currently only have 718MB.

Currently the storage is not unified and I have moved as much to the SD card as I can.

I am guessing that to update I will have to do something like

1. backup with kies
2. uninstall as many apps as I can
3. do upgrade
4. reinstall apps
5. restore backup

and hope I don't lose too much.

Will any data on the sdcard be corrupted erased?

Should I move applications back to the internal storage before I start?

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: If you read the description of the tag you used for [android] by  hovering over it, you will see your question is off topic. I have voted to migrate this to the [android.se] site where your question is on topic. Please don't double post.